# SSIS Flat File source- Get rid of some embedded unwanted double quotes

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, etl, business-intelligence

I referred few threads related to this issue and couldn't find a proper solution yet. So just asking this question - Is there any way to automatically remove unwanted double quotes in a csv text delimited file before loading to sql-database using SSIS dataflow. I am using a flat file connection manager as below:

[image]

See the sample data:

```
"FirstName","LastName","Target"
"Jim","Tunsh","20 \ HC"
"Tim","Harkin"","40 \" HC"
"George","Washington","30 \ HC"
```

You can see there is an unwanted double-quote at the second row after the slash. I am trying to replace that with an empty space or something.

I tried derived column with a regular expression like below:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([Target],"\" ","")))
```

Not seems to be working

Please share if you have better idea.

Comment: The CSV data `"40 \" HC"` is not correctly encoded. According to [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) it should be `"40 \"" HC"` (note the extra `"` character after the backslash).

Comment: The file also has a misplaced extra quote in `"Harkin""`.

Comment: Thanks!
Yes. Technically the file is in wrong format. But that is how it generated by a data factory module. Extra quote around name can be corrected in data entry

Answer (score 0):

May not be a great solution, but this issue is resolved by removing all double-quotes within that field.
For this, added a derived column and written an expression to remove quotes for the desired column and replaced that column.

```
REPLACE([Target],"\"","")
```

[image]